# Is there a wmv writer in vtk?

Tags: c#, .net, vtk, wmv

I am recording a video using vtkAVIWriter which writes .avi file, Is there a way to generate .wmv file using other writer, I have searched but did not find any suitable writer for wmv format.

here is code to generate .avi file

```
    private void WriteAVIFile(RenderWindowControl renderWindowControl, string fileName)
    {
        using (var movieWriter = vtkAVIWriter.New())
        {
            var imageFilter = vtkWindowToImageFilter.New();
            imageFilter.SetInput(renderWindowControl.RenderWindow);
            imageFilter.Update();

            movieWriter.SetInputConnection(imageFilter.GetOutputPort());

            movieWriter.SetQuality(2);
            movieWriter.SetRate(4);
            movieWriter.SetFileName(fileName + ".avi");

            movieWriter.Update();
            movieWriter.Start();

            //perform some action
            var renderer = renderWindowControl.RenderWindow.GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer();
            var camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                camera.Roll(i);
                renderer.GetRenderWindow().Render();
                imageFilter.Modified();
                imageFilter.Update();
                movieWriter.Write();
            }

            movieWriter.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do know the difference between container-formats and audio/video codecs, right?

Comment: Yes, which is why I was expecting some other writer type instead of AVI.